# Retrieving a variable from within a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, riot-games-api

I am attempting to pull information from the League of Legends API.

To simplify what I am doing, I am attempting to pull information about a user and their previous matches. The problem that I run into is that when I parse a JSON request, it returns a champion ID rather than their name (Ex: 412 rather than "Thresh").

The only solution I can see for this would be to make another JSON request and parse that data for the champion name. Currently what I have looks like this.

```
$.getJSON(championMasteryPHP, function (json) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        var champID = json[i].championId;
        var championInfo = "http://example.com/champInfo.php?summonerid=" + champID;

    $.getJSON(championInfo, function (json2) {
        var champName = json2.name;
    });

    $('#champ').append("<li>"+champID+" - "+champName+"</li>")
    }
});
```

I'm unable to access the `champName` variable due to it being nested within the second JSON function.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: just append the li inside your nested chanpionInfo call? Also, its json2.name and not json.name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$.getJSON(championMasteryPHP, function (json) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        var champID = json[i].championId;
        var championInfo = "http://example.com/champInfo.php?summonerid=" + champID;

    $.getJSON(championInfo, function (json2) {
        var champName = json2.name;
        $('#champ').append("<li>"+champID+" - "+champName+"</li>")
    });
    }
});
```

Just put it inside the second json request since you need to wait till that request is done anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You should put the append statement in the callback because **[getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)** is an asynchronous method (does mean the Request is running in the background, and calls your function back when it got a response), so you should wait for the response first then you can append it to `#champ` :

```
$.getJSON(championMasteryPHP, function (json) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        var champID = json[i].championId;
        var championInfo = "http://example.com/champInfo.php?summonerid=" + champID;

        $.getJSON(championInfo, function (json2) {
             var champName = json.name;

             $('#champ').append("<li>"+champID+" - "+champName+"</li>")
        });

    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Small question,

After moving the append statement, now my first call loops so my end result looks like this.

http://i.imgur.com/Cp5SpX0.png

It is looping the last item in the list (Id 58 for example). What did I do wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you expecting as result, but that really depending to the Json response. (just small note : instead of `20` better if you use `json.length`).

Comment: What I'm attempting to do is get this data    

http://pastebin.com/H1hbCJXJ    

But it does not contain champion names, just their ID. Because of this I need to parse individual data for each champion ID to get their name. That looks like this.    

http://pastebin.com/CWZ1R0Pg    

The problem I'm running into now is that my first parse will freeze on my last result in the data set rather than looping in the for loop and pulling every result. It looks like this.    

http://i.imgur.com/Cp5SpX0.png    

rather than this    

http://i.imgur.com/y91HRJ3.png